# An actor performing a use case on behalf of another actor in UML use case

Tags: uml, actor, use-case

My question is: when there are two actors in a use case, and one performs a specific use case or action for themselves, but there is another actor which can perform that same use case/action for the other actor (with a couple additional steps), do they both point to the same use case?

I have a scenario below:

So, I have two actors: Student and Counselor (Both are Users).

A student can create their own schedule.
A counselor can create a schedule for a student (i.e. on behalf of another student, not themselves). In this scenario, the teacher must also search for a student (which the student does not have to do in their use case). I'm guessing this could possibly << extend >> the "Create Schedule", but again it's only applicable for the Counselor actor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A use case shall always express the added value the system under consideration creates for the actor. So "... on behalf" does not express the added value. Rather you should model this with a single use case and express the "on behalf" as a constraint. It can be done either by adding a role (the User you named)

[image]

Or you can also do it directly like this:

[image]

Comment: I think in the second diagram, the Counselor shall also be linked to "Create schedule". Otherwise he's formally associated with no use case.

Comment: I disagree with your view point of added value: first UML standard doesn't refer to "added value" as far as I know. Second, I can ensure you that in some domain areas, functions for acting on behalf are frequently of importance when discussing use case with user representatives during the analysis of business requirements.  Claiming that it's of no added value is a personal judgment not based on any facts (unless you've already decided on the design of your app, and that in this context you wouldn't see any difference).

Comment: @Christophe Well, the UML spec talks merely about the syntax of the language, rather than of its usage (only by example). However, I warmly recommend Bittner/Spence to find out about the added value. UC synthesis is very often taken the wrong way and used for functional decomposition. Re the link in 2nd dia: No. The added value applies to Student. Counselor just has "additional work to do". The value goes to the student. The constraint clarifies the situation completely.